# 3D curve cut by a plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I'm looking for a way to do this kind of pictures with `pgfplots`.
More precisely I need to make 2 pictures :

- one to draw any 3D shape with a vertical plane (with some transparency) cutting it

[image: 1st image]
or
[image: 2nd image]

- one to draw the same 3D shape cutted by the same plane but only showing the curve on one side of the plane. The main goal is to see the 2D restriction of the curve over a plane / the intersection of the plane and the curve.

[image: 3rd image]

Does anyone have an idea?

[image: first image]

[image: second one]

Sources :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342244/how-can-i-create-a-slice-of-a-surface-plot-to-create-a-line-matlab

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/280132-how-to-cut-a-3d-plane-with-a-line

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and note that not all users here are familiar with matlab. Notice also that pgfplots is not a computer algebra system.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an answer to your question. One reason why I cannot answer this question is that I do not know matlab. The other reason is that it seems to me that you are asking several questions at a time. So I focus on the question

> Can one add a plane to a 3D plot made by pgfplots?

The answer is

> Yes ...

... if you are willing to do things step by step.

Starting point of my answer is [an example from pgfplots.net by Stefan Kottwitz](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/fill-space-3d/), which I slightly modified. The most important change I made was to change the border from `15pt` to `3.14mm`. And then I changed a sign, used `declare function` to simplify things a bit, and (I almost forgot) also added a plane.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=8-(\x*\x+\y*\y)/4;}]
  \pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
  \pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}
  \begin{axis}[
      hide axis,
      domain = -4:4,
      zmax   = 12,
      colormap/bone
    ]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{pre main}
      \addplot3 [surf] {f(x,y)};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \addplot3 [name path = xline, draw = none] (x,-4,0);
    \addplot3 [name path = yline, draw = none] (4,y,0);
    \addplot3 [name path = xcurve, y domain = 0:0, draw = none]
      (x, -4, {f(x,4)});
    \addplot3 [name path = ycurve, y domain = 0:0, draw = none]
      (4, x, {f(x,4)});
    \addplot [left color = black, right color = black!50, draw = none]
      fill between[of = xcurve and xline];
    \addplot [left color = black!50, right color = black, draw = none]
      fill between[of = yline and ycurve, reverse = true];
    \fill[gray!20,opacity=0.314] plot[variable=\x,smooth,samples=25,domain=-4:2] (0,\x,{f(\x,0)})
    to[out=0,in=162,tension=1.2] (0,4,{4.78})
    -- (0,4,12) -- (0,-4,12) -- cycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you marmot, I precised a bit more the question. I would like to show what happened / what is the 2D shape when cutting a curve with a plane. I really know that tikz-pgf is not a CAS and I'm ready to provide to it any needed curve equation

Comment: @Yoshi Your question has unfortunately been closed. In my above example, it is trivial to show the surface at the cut because I chose the cutting plane along some fixed `x`, here `x=0`. Consequently, the function will just be `f(0,y)`. In general, it is slightly more tricky, but not much. I was actually working at something that draws the plane in the general case, but before I finished your question was closed.

Comment: I've seen that I need any moderator or user who ask the post to be holded for it to be reopened but I'n not pretty sure on how to contact them.

Comment: @Yoshi At present, there are 2 reopen votes, one from me. I am not too optimistic that this will work out. Part of the reason is that you changed your question rather late, so it is already out of the focus of many. I don't know what the "cleanest" way to go is, but one possibility is that you ask a new question (and do whatever you think is appropriate with my answer, i.e. accept it or let it be). If you decide to do so, try to make the question as specific as possible.